# Can the datetime module in Python be formatted to output double digit numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am learning about the datetime module in Python and I tried to print the day, month and year.
It works but the date is being printed as a single digit instead of double digits.
Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
dateNow = datetime.now()
print (dateNow.day)
print (dateNow.month)
print (dateNow.year)
```

Here is the output:

```
1
4
2021
>>>
```

I would like it to be shown as
01
04
2021

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `strftime`:

```
print(dateNow.strftime('%d %m %Y'))
```

It gives as expected `01 04 2021`